# Remove Custom Progress Dialog borders

Tags: android, progress-bar, border, customization, progressdialog

I have created a custom progress dialog drawables.

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ABCDEF</item>
        <item name="android:textColor"> @color/heading</item>
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
         <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>

    </style>

    <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
         <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
      <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:centerBright">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:centerDark">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:fullBright">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:fullDark">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:topBright">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:topDark">@color/grey</item>
    </style>
```

Everything is working fine, its showing the things as it should. But dialog is showing borders. I want to remove those borders [screen shot attached].

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to your `CustomAlertDialogStyle` too:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```